# BigQuery >> Extract Value for Dictionary Key in JSON Object

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a string object in a table column with structure:

```
[{"__food": "true"},{"item": "1"},{"toppings": "true"},{"__discount_amount": "4.95"},{"__original_price": "24.95"}]
```

How can I extract the value `true` from the `toppings` key from this?

I tried turning it into JSON first but `json_extract(parse_json(string_object_column), '$.toppings')` just returns null

The closest I got was keeping it as a string and doing
`json_extract(string_object_column, '$[0]')`

Which gets me:
`{"toppings":"true"}`

Is this doable without unnesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try and consider below approach using [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('[{"__food": "true"},{"item": "1"},{"toppings": "true"},{"__discount_amount": "4.95"},{"__original_price": "24.95"}]', r'"toppings": "(\D+)"}') as EXTRACT_TOPPINGS
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

You may just update the REGEX to make it more strict based on your use case.

Comment: Yeah regex does seem to be the best approach. I wanted to avoid it in favor of some dict comprehension approach but the JSON is hard to work with. Thanks!